# Convert symlinks to hard links

Tags: bash, find, symbolic-link

I'd like to recursively convert soft links to hard links in a directory. I've tried something like this:

```bsh
for f in *; do (mv $f{,~} && ln $(readlink $f~) && rm $f~) done
```

…but it has two major problems:

- not recursive
- picks up files that are not symbolic links

It would be nice to somehow feed the above line to `find -type l`, but i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: See also [this discussion][1] (`cp -aH`).


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94185/convert-soft-to-hardlinks-with-cp

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This command should work:

```
find -type l -exec bash -c 'ln -f "$(readlink -m "$0")" "$0"' {} \;
```

How it works:

- `find -type l` finds all links in the current directory.
- `-exec bash -c '...' {} \;` invokes bash to execute `...`.

  It passes `{}` – the name of the link that's currently being processed ‐ as an argument, which bash can access as `$0`.
- `readlink -m "$0"` returns the absolute path of the symbolic link's destination.
- `ln -f "$(readlink -m "$0")" "$0"` overwrites (`-f`) the symbolic link `$0` with a hard link to its target.

If the link cannot be converted for some reason, it will remain untouched and ln will print an error message.

Comment: Regarding that last paragraph, wouldn't it suffice to specify absolute paths to `bash` and `ln`?

Comment: My problem was that *readlink* returns a relative path by default, but the `-e` switch fixes that.

Comment: What would be the command for OSX?

Comment: @IgorMarkelov I'm sorry, but I have no clue when it comes to OSX.

Comment: On a Mac it is: ```brew install coreutils``` and ```find * -type l -exec bash -c 'ln -f "$(greadlink -m "$0")" "$0"' {} \;```.

Comment: Nice! And even works with spaces in names.